# Are there variables associated with xrange limits in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

In a gnuplot script, I'd like the x2range be a function of xrange, even when the xrange is set automatically by gnuplot. If there are pre-defined variables associated with the two limits of xrange, this can be done easily. I searched for such variables, but didn't find any.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no such funcion `get xrange` in gnuplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked `help link`?

from the gnuplot documentation:

> ...
>   The set link command establishes a mapping between the x and x2 axes,
>   or the y and y2 axes.  maps primary axis coordinates onto
>   the secondary axis.  maps secondary axis coordinates onto
>   the primary axis.
>   ...

Also type `show var GPVAL_X`

and you will get:

```
Variables beginning with GPVAL_X:
GPVAL_X_MIN = 0.0
GPVAL_X_MAX = 200.0
GPVAL_X_LOG = 10.0
GPVAL_X2_MIN = 0.0
GPVAL_X2_MAX = 199.0
GPVAL_X2_LOG = 10.0
```

But these values are (of course) set only *after* plotting and are "read only". But you can plot your graph, read these values and adjust your range accordingly and replot.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.